# How do you run a lambda function to run a multi-criteria sort in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following df with much more dates.

```
df = {'Date': ('10/6/2015', '10/7/2015'),
         'CAD 12M PR': (-7.4, -4.9),
         'AUD 12M PR': (-2.3, -1.6),
         'NOK 12M PR': (2.6, 8.6),
         'SEK 12M PR': (6.7, 8.6),
         'NZD 12M PR': (3.1, 2.9),
         'EUR 12M PR': (2.7, 4.7),
         'GBP 12M PR': (-3.6, -2.5),
         'JPY 12M PR': (13.8, 15.7),
         'CAD 1Y ZS': (3.1, 2.5),
         'AUD 1Y ZS': (-1.7, -3.0),
         'NOK 1Y ZS': (2.0, 1.8),
         'SEK 1Y ZS': (2.6, 2.6),
         'NZD 1Y ZS': (-4.5, -5.6),
         'EUR 1Y ZS': (-3.8, -3.7),
         'GBP 1Y ZS': (-1.6, -2.7),
          'JPY 1Y ZS': (3.0, 2.1)
         }
```

In the df there are 8 currencies (CAD, AUD, NOK, SEK, NZD, EUR, GBP, JPY) and 2 different data points: 12M PR (12 month price return) and 1Y ZS (1 year z score). I'd like to create a new portfolio (list) with the top 2 buys/sells from this df. For the first sort, I'd like to rank the 12M PR from largest to smallest and put the top 4-ranked currencies by 12M PR in the "buy bucket" and bottom 4-ranked by 12M PR in the "sell bucket." The second sort is based off the 1Y ZS. For buys, I want the 2 currencies with the highest 1Y ZS (from the top 4-ranked 12M PR bucket), and for sells I want the 2 currencies with the lowest 1Y ZS (from the bottom 4-ranked 12M PR bucket).

For 10/6/2015, the top 4-ranked currencies by 12M PR are JPY, SEK, NZD, and EUR. From that bucket, JPY and SEK have the highest 1Y ZS so they'd be the buys. The bottom 4-ranked currencies by 12M PR are CAD, GBP, AUD, and NOK. From that bucket, AUD and GBP have the lowest 1Y ZS so they are the sells.

To get the largest 12M PR among the currencies, I tried:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(1).values[-1] in [['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']], axis=1)
```

And to get the smallest 12M PR among the currencies, I tried:

```
df.apply(lambda row: row.nsmallest(1).values[-1] in [['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR', 'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']], axis=1)
```

For both I got this error:

```
TypeError: ("Cannot use method 'nlargest' with dtype object", 'occurred at index 0')
```

My plan was to use the above code to sort the 12M PR into the buy/sell buckets and then do the same thing to find the 1st/2nd largest/smallest among the 1Y ZS-

Answer (score 0):

You should try a `df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype)` on your original dataframe. What you'll see is that all of your data is converted to `object` because there are mixed types (the dates are objects).

For example:

```py
df.info()
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 17 columns):
Date          2 non-null object
CAD 12M PR    2 non-null float64
AUD 12M PR    2 non-null float64
NOK 12M PR    2 non-null float64
SEK 12M PR    2 non-null float64
NZD 12M PR    2 non-null float64
EUR 12M PR    2 non-null float64
GBP 12M PR    2 non-null float64
JPY 12M PR    2 non-null float64
CAD 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
AUD 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
NOK 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
SEK 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
NZD 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
EUR 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
GBP 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
JPY 1Y ZS     2 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(16), object(1)
memory usage: 352.0+ bytes
```

And when you try those mixed types inside the apply:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x.dtype)
```

You'll get:

```
Date          object
CAD 12M PR    object
AUD 12M PR    object
NOK 12M PR    object
SEK 12M PR    object
NZD 12M PR    object
EUR 12M PR    object
GBP 12M PR    object
JPY 12M PR    object
CAD 1Y ZS     object
AUD 1Y ZS     object
NOK 1Y ZS     object
SEK 1Y ZS     object
NZD 1Y ZS     object
EUR 1Y ZS     object
GBP 1Y ZS     object
JPY 1Y ZS     object
```

... due to the mixed types.

Instead, you should make the dates a `DateTimeIndex` so all the dtypes in your columns are floats.

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
```

This will give you values to which you can apply `nlargest`. I didn’t apply any of your additional logic, as I assume your main issue is dtypes.

*However, you should post your expected result for a more complete answer.* I suspect that the way you're applying this, you will get the largest 12M PR for each currency across all dates (equivalent to `max`). If you wanted the top 4, you would need to do an additional `nlargest(4)` to capture those. For example,

```py
df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR',
       'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].max(axis=0).nlargest(4)
```

provides the 4 largest 12M PR scores for all dates and currencies. This may or may not be what you've intended, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the the dtypes and for your answer! Sorry for not being more clear, but your answer did help me find what I was looking for.

'df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR',
       'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].apply(lambda row: row.nlargest(2).values[-1],axis=1)' <- this code finds the nlargest or nsmallest in the above columns by each row

Comment: and this code gives you the column label of the nlargest/nsmallest in the selected columns by row label.
'df[['CAD 12M PR', 'AUD 12M PR', 'NOK 12M PR', 'SEK 12M PR', 'NZD 12M PR',
       'EUR 12M PR', 'GBP 12M PR', 'JPY 12M PR']].T.apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(1).idxmax())'

Thanks again!